# How to change default shell in a GCE VM instance?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, zsh

I've successfully created and logged into a GCE VM with `ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine <EXTERNAL IP>`.

The VM is running ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I've installed zsh. I've verified that the output of `which zsh` appears in `/etc/shells`.

When I try to run `chsh -s $(which zsh)` I'm prompted for a password and I have no idea what to enter.

When I created `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` (which was created during a `gcloud ssh` command issued earlier) I didn't enter a passphrase for the ssh key.

How can I change my shell?

EDIT: Here's what I see when I've logged in:

```
paymahn@paymahn:~$ chsh -s $(which zsh)
Password:
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't need to create a password, just use `sudo`

```
# for current logged user
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh "$USER"
```

Comment: These commands will fail on GCE buster images with `chsh: user 'paymahn' does not exist in /etc/passwd` (or similar for whatever your username is).

Answer (score 1):

In GCP VM's they don't come with a password by default so you'll first need to change the password using `sudo passwd` then you can use the root password for your `zsh` shell.

Comment: still fails - anything to check following the password change? I just changed passwd, then re-ran chsh and have PAM error again

Answer (score 1):

Add a `$(which zsh)` to your `.profile`

Comment: this looks like it has potential but the instructions are lacking. could you please explain how to add it into .profile? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out, kinda. I don't think I had a password set at all. I ran `sudo passwd paymahn` to create a password and then used the newly created password during the prompt for `chsh`.

Comment: When I execute `passwd` I receive the following error: `passwd: Authentication token manipulation error`

Comment: same as @PapaSmurf , need help

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo passwd <your username>`?

Comment: This didn't work for me -- still see PAM error after following this suggestion

Answer (score -1):

Clarifying/combining existing answers (here's what worked for me anyway):

1. do `sudo passwd $USER`, to give yourself a password
2. then do `chsh -s /bin/zsh $USER` (**without** the `sudo` prefix)